# SSH -- Open in browser window (GCP) isn't working

Tags: ssh, gcp

I have a virtual machine in Google Cloud Platform. I have been able until this morning to open a window using "SSH Open in browser window". I haven't changed anything.  I stopped the machine and restarted. That didn't help. Since, I can't open a window so I have no access to config files. How do I go about fixing this?
I issued the following command and I get this error:

```
  $ gcloud compute config-ssh
Updating project ssh metadata...working..Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/records-preservation].                                                                               
Updating project ssh metadata...done.                                                                                                                                                                 
You should now be able to use ssh/scp with your instances.
For example, try running:

  $ ssh linux-web-server.us-central1-c.records-preservation

info@cloudshell:/usr/lib/cgi-bin (records-preservation)$ ssh linux-web-server.us-central1-c.records-preservation
info@34.29.26.203: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Thanks,
-Marcos